# LinSched source for 2.6.35 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, simulation, scheduler

I have been trying to obtain the source for the version of LinSched (user space simulator for the CFS scheduler) for kernel 2.6.35 but I am not able to find it anywhere.

This is the original git repo of LinSched for 2.6.32, which mentions that this version is deprecated and I should refer to [here](http://google3-2.osuosl.org/?p=linsched/2.6.35.git;a=summary). Unfortunately, this link is broken. I also tried cloning the repo mentioned [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-scheduler-simulator/index.html), but

```
git clone git://google3-2.osuosl.org/linsched/2.6.35.git
```

throws an error:

```
"fatal: Unable to look up google3-2.osuosl.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)"
```

Any idea how I can obtain the source for this? Was this project discontinued for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mailed the maintainer/developer and obtained the correct link. The link can be found [here](https://github.com/paulturner/LinSched)

Comment: Nope, not anymore - coincidentally rhymes with `404`.

Answer (score 4):

The repository has now been moved to git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pjt/linsched.git