# LinSched 2.6.35 no valid link to checkout

Tags: linux, scheduler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LinSched source for 2.6.35 kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412372/linsched-source-for-2-6-35-kernel)

I´ve been looking for the `LinSched 2.6.35` for some time,but all the links available in web don´t work. Anyone who have the source code of `LinSched 2.6.35`, could you please send me one copy of that? Thx!

Comment: I think you will find the answer [here][1] on SO. 

CHEERS!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412372/linsched-source-for-2-6-35-kernel

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway still no working. The link suggested in the first answer is, https://github.com/paulturner/LinSched , butit shows the page can´t be found. In the second link git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pjt/linsched.git, is the LinSched version 3.3. Wheres what I am looking for is the version for 2.6.35.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did some hunting around on the internet, and I found the repository here:  (git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pjt/linsched.git) . I have confirmed that it exists. I checked this before I put the link in. I really am not entirely sure why, but this piece of code has moved around a lot on the internet, and there are a lot of broken links. A hint as to why this code has been somewhat elusive is that the author may not be very proud of how clean his coding is.

I have confirmed that the branch you are looking for, 2.6.35 is there by typing:

```
 git ls-branch git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pjt/linsched.git | grep 2.6.35
```

I noticed a number of release candidates, perhaps you will be most interested in rc6?

I hope this will help you.

CHEERS.

Comment: First of all, your help is really appreciated(I tried to mark your answer to be useful, but can´t due to my lack of enough reputation... )

Comment: I have also checked this link                                     [link](git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pjt/linsched.git, and was able to check out the reposity, and by git switching to the linsched-alpha branch, i was able to obtain the files of linsched 3.3.  I tried as you suggested, but in my case, the git ls-branch doesn´t work, showing 'ls-branch' is not a git command. I am not sure how you worked that.

Comment: Also, I think the 2.6.35 you detected is actually the version of Linux kernel maintained by Linus Torvalds. To see why, you can check the [link](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pjt/linsched/)  you´ll find the linsched-alpha under the Branches dir, it is the version for 3.3. While under the Tags dir, there are a list of different versions of Linux Kernel.

Comment: @coder, I'm happy that what I wrote helped you. I think you can still accept it as the answer. Anyway, don't worry about it too much, you have the right spirit of community here. That is, when an answer is helpful you upvote, or accept it as you are able. CHEERS!

Comment: Hi, have you figured out if the 2.6.35 you grepped out is really the LinSched or just the linux kernel? I need this version because it has some APIs that can help to create tasks with specified workload, while other versions like 2.6.32 and 3.3 don´t have it.

Comment: AFIK it is LinSched, I found the link from the project author after some chasing it down. I don't remember what the threads were that I chased down. CHEERS